# Does Ruby recalculate array size every time when you call `array.size`?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Could someone provide some proofs, whether Ruby recalculates array size every time when you call `array.size`, `array.length` or `array.count`?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

To make things clearer, by `recalculate` I mean, whether Ruby needs to loop through the whole array again and again to calculate the number of its elements every time when we call `array.size`.

Comment: No, Ruby keeps track of the array size. Calling `array.size` has virtually no overhead.

Comment: @Stefan, that's interesting and useful information. What about hashes, sets, ranges, strings? What about enumerators derived from arrays, such as `[1,2,3].each`?

Comment: Marian13, your question is somewhat ambiguous because it unclear what you mean by "recalculate". One might argue that whenever a method is invoked or the value of a variable is retrieved a "calculation" takes place. I interpreted your question as being a practical one, asking whether, for example, `n = arr1.size; arr2.select { |x| x < n }` is *substantially more efficient* than `arr2.select { |x| x < arr1.size }`, something I've wondered about myself. To use @Stefan's words, perhaps you are asking whether "Ruby keeps track of the array size"?

Comment: @Cary Swoveland, You interpreted my question correctly. "Whether Ruby keeps track of the array size?" is exactly what I want to know. I will update my question to make things clearer.

Comment: @Stefan Could you provide some links, where you have found that Ruby keeps track of the array size, e.g. docs, articles, books?

Comment: Marian13, @Stefan probably knows that because he's memorized Ruby's C code.

Comment: I looked it up once. You can easily verify it by benchmarking `size` for a 10-element and a 10-million-element array – there shouldn’t be any difference (don’t measure the array creation time though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pragmatically Speaking, Array#length is Dynamic in Ruby

Your question can't really be answered canonically, because the lookup and storage implementations of arrays is often platform- and VM-specific. However, as a practical matter, from the Ruby interpreter's persepctive the answer is *yes* because each call sends a *message* to an Array object, asking it to return its current length.

Some languages store the current length of the array as an element of the array itself. Other approaches exist, too. In Ruby 2.7.1:

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_length(VALUE ary)
{
    long len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
    return LONG2NUM(len);
}
```

the C implementation appears to retrieve the stored length of the array at the time of the call, but you'd have to dig deeper into the source code if you want to understand all the ins-and-outs of how the VM optimizes this (or not).

Comment: The implementation at https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/include/ruby/internal/core/rarray.h#L131 appears to run in constant time by querying stored length.

Comment: In fact [`RARRAY`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/7bafc9f433223d82aac8e8974b9bfdbdc34ca4df/include/ruby/internal/core/rarray.h#L42) appears to store the length in a [C Struct](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/7bafc9f433223d82aac8e8974b9bfdbdc34ca4df/include/ruby/internal/core/rarray.h#L87) and all  `RARRAY_LEN(ary)` does is fetch that value (`RARRAY(s)->len`)

Comment: The core classes are essential for performance. And although this isn’t documented, I’d be very surprised to see a Ruby implementation that doesn’t optimize these.